# Unable to call Oracle Stored Procedures from SSRS Reporting Manager

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, oracle12c

We had recently upgraded our database from Oracle 11g to Oracle 12c. After upgrading, while testing the reports from Reporting service manager I am facing a strange issue i.e., Where ever there is call to a Oracle stored procedure it will return an error saying

> Query execution failed for the dataset xxxxxxxx

I had checked the windows logs also to check what the exact error is and the log shows as below

> **ERROR**: Throwing Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ProcessingAbortedException:   Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ProcessingAbortedException: An error has occurred during report processing.
>
> ---> Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessingException: Query execution failed for dataset 'xxxxxxx'.
>
> ---> System.Data.OracleClient.OracleException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
>   PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'xxxxx'
>   ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
>   PL/SQL: Statement ignored

I checked whether wrong number of arguments are getting passed but procedure contains only one input value and one output value and the input value has to be passed from the report.

I googled for the solution and I can see many issues facing the same error. I tried all the ways such as installing odp.net provider for the oracle 12c version and restarting reporting services. But nothing worked out for me.

Please help me in solving this error.

Comment: Have you tried to run the PL\SQL query in SQL Developer?

Comment: Yes I tried.It works as expected.

Comment: Does the report run on your development machine?

Comment: Yes I do tried. It returns an error stating ORA 010301-Insufficient Privileges.I also checked the Privileges but all looks good to me because the same Privileges were applied in the Oracle 11g version of database

Comment: In SQL Developer, when it ran successfully, which account were you executing the SQL? If the error says it's a privileges error, it has to be the account you're using.

Comment: Are you using a service account for the data source on the report server?

Comment: Yes. We are using a service account to connect with oracle from the reporting manager. I had given execute privileges to the service account in the stored procedure

Comment: Try to execute the stored procedure with the service account in SQL Developer. If there is no issue, it may be a double hop authentication issue.

Comment: Did my answer help?

Answer (score 0):

This may be a Kerberos and double hop issue. You need to enable Kerberos delegation on your reporting services server as well as set up an SPN so that Kerberos can pass the credentials of the user running the report instead of the Service Account for SSRS.

More details can be found here: https://serverfault.com/q/378096/85935